# I get this error when running this calculator app

Tags: r

this is my code:

server

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$oput <- renderText({
    
    switch(input$ops,
           "Addition" = input$first + input$second,
           "Substraction" = input$first - input$second,
           "Multiplication" = input$first * input$second,
           "Division" = input$first / input$second,
           )
    
    
  })
  
})
```

UI

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage)
  titlePanel("Simple Calculator")
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("first", "Select a Number", 10),
      numericInput("second", "Select Another Number", 10),
      selectInput("ops", "Select Operation",
                  choices = c("Addition","Substraction","Multiplication","Division"))
    
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h2("The final result is:"),
      textOutput("oput")
    )
  )
```

I searched and found out that it can be related to putting new lines and spaces after function names but can't find where the problem lies.
i will be thankful for any help.

Comment: this is the error i get : Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You have fundamental syntax errors in your code.  For example `shinyUI(fluidPage); titlePanel("Simple Calculator")`.  I suggest you create a new app file using File > New File > Shiny Web App... in RStudio and adapt the template code to your needs.  Once you have the correct syntax, your code works as expected.

Comment: I did this, and now it says Error sourcing C:\Users\H\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpiy5PMF\file537432c2c2f.